# How to make JSP page extend abstract HttpServlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, abstract, extends

I'm working on a Web application that works with multiple tables in a database. The design requirements specify that each table have its own page to work with. For the most part, a good chunk of the server-side code is the same across all the pages, with the page specific stuff mostly dealing with the sql for the specific tables (and they all have different structures, BTW).

So I thought it would be prudent to organize the code so that all the common methods were all in one shared place and leaving only the unique implementations on the JSP pages.

The structure I have attempted to create is to have an abstract superclass, which we will call `MyServlet`, that extends `HttpServlet`. Each of my JSP pages extend this superclass.

However when I went to test this out my pages now fail to load with `HTTP 405 Method not allowed` error.

For security/business reasons I cannot simply copy and paste my code here, but I can post a general structure. My Servlet class looks something like this:

```
public abstract class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
     public void someMethod()
     {
          abstractMethod();
     }

     protected abstract void abstractMethod();
}
```

And my jsp like this:

```
<%@ extends="package.MyServlet" %>
<%! 
     public void abstractMethod()
     {
          someCode;
     }
%>
<% someMethod() %>
```

I should point out that `MyServlet` does not implement `doGet()` or `doPost()`. I was under the assumption that with JSP pages themselves being extensions of `HttpServlet` that they provided implementations for those methods, though I am also aware that error 405 happens because at least `doGet()` is not there.

Is the error happening because I have not implemented `doGet()`, and if so how do I implement it such that it works with my JSP pages? Or is there some other reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: stop putting java code in jsp files.  that was fine in 1997, but it is terrible in 2005 (and beyond).

Comment: How else am I supposed to do this? I tried using forwarding from seperate Servlets, but then I ran into either closing the ResultSet before I could actually use it (it is a major help if I can write directly from the ResultSet to the page instead of having to convert it into some other format like xml first), or not being able to properly close the Connection.

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing this without writing java code into your jsp.

Answer (score 2):

can you just create your method in some utility class and then include it, instead of extending it?

```
<%@ page import="org.foo.HelperClass, org.foo.StaticHelper" %>
 <%! 
 HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
 %>
 Helper Stuff: <%= helper.someMethod() %><br/>
 Static Stuff: <%= StaticHelper.someStaticMethod() %>
```

would this accomplish your goal?

Comment: This is actually how I did it originally, using static methods from a helper class, and that worked fine. It's just that had my theory worked out it could have eliminated a good chunk of code from scriptlets across all my pages.

Comment: Alternativley, do all the work in servlets, and set attributes in the request with the servlet, and use JSTL to access them

Answer (score 0):

I like this basic orgainzation of a servlet and JSP web application

1. Business code (including database access) is in the servlet (or a business layer that is called by the servlet).
2. JSP is exclusively for presentation of data and retrieval of user input.

If you have a resultSet and want to present it, load the information that must be presented into a Collection (I like List) and set it in an appropriate scope (session, page, request, most likely not application).